# Setup.py not found, when installing package from GitHub

Tags: python, github

I am trying to install the gsv8_python3 package from Github (https://github.com/me-systeme/gsv8pypi_python3) to my python, but python gives me following error:

ERROR: gsv8pypi_python3 from git+https://github.com/me-systeme/gsv8pypi_python3.git#egg=gsv8pypi_python3 does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' n
or 'pyproject.toml' found.

I don't really know what to do, maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

gsv8_python3 is not a traditional python package, so you cannot install it through a package manager. Please clone the code and use/implement it in your project directly.

Comment: And how do I do that exactly? Im sorry, Im really new to programming :/

Comment: No worries! If you have git installed, you can do ``git clone https://github.com/me-systeme/gsv8pypi_python3`` and it will pull the files. Be sure that you have git installed.

Comment: Update: When you clone the project, open ``gsv8.html``. It appears to have information about the project. Hopefully, this is useful to you!

Comment: Oh I have git and I just did what you said and I think everything is installes now!
But when I run the code I still get "no module named gsv8" :/

Comment: What do you mean by open gsv8.html?

Comment: When you pull the files with git, there is a file in the project called ``gsv8.html``, you can open it and it will load in your browser.

Comment: What code are you running? How are you interacting with gsv8?

Comment: I just want to use the methods of gsv8 and to give out the data from a serial port

Comment: I believe that my original answer covers this, but you also need to know the fundamental calling of methods from another file, please look into https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-file/